# Writing a Node module in TypeScript for consumption by both TS and JS projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

I have an Express middleware project written in TypeScript. I'd like to consume it in both JS & TS based Node projects.

I'm having trouble configuring my projects to ensure that

- the upstream project is outputting modules that can be consumed by Node
- my module can be consumed in JS projects in the format `myGreatFunction = require('myGreatFunction') // typeof = function`
- my module can be consumed in the format `import myGreatFunction from 'myGreatFunction' // typeof = function`
- my module is not being either output as an object with a .default when that is not expected, or, vice-versa, not being done so when that is indeed expected.

It feels as though I can only achieve some of these aims but not others.

What is the correct incantation of TSConfig properties (upstream & downstream) to ensure this is so?

---

In the end I settled on a compromise - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I settled on a compromise:

**Library TSConfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

**Library:**

```
export = function myGroovyFunction() {...}
```

**Downstream project, TypeScript**

```
import * as myGroovyFunction from 'mygroovyfunction';
```

**Downstream project, JavaScript**

```
const myGroovyFunction = require('mygroovyfunction');
```

---

The TypeScript import isn't quite as concise as I'd like, but I can deal.

Answer (score 1):

## Library

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
}
```

`module.ts`:

```
export class MyClass {
  static Version: string = "1.0";
}
```

When we compile this module we'll get:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.Version = "1.0";
    return MyClass;
}());
exports.MyClass = MyClass;
```

## TS Client

client.ts:

```
import {MyClass} from "./../src/module";

console.log(MyClass.Version);
```

compile and run `node client.js` - see "1.0"

## JS Client

Just grad the same code from compiled ts client :

```
var module_1 = require("./../src/module");
console.log(module_1.MyClass.Version);
```

same output obviously

Answer (score 0):

1. Using a typescript file in typescript.

   ```
   Assuming B.ts is the typescript file that you want to use in A.ts, then:

       import { B's module that are exported } from 'path/to/B';  // notice there is no extension mentioned here.

   Also B must have a export module in it.
   ```
2. Using a ts file in a js file.

   ```
   B.ts = file which you want to use in your main file.
   A.js = your main file.
   In your A.js:

       var external = require('path/to/B'); // notice there is no extension mentioned here.
   ```